# ClientID not set. Either set it on a <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT_ID" /> tag, or pass clientId when initializing GoogleSignIn

Tags: flutter

I get an error from my log in my app when ever i try to click sign in with google it shows this so please  i need help
`ClientID not set. Either set it on a <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT_ID" /> tag, or pass clientId when initializing GoogleSignIn`

Answer (score 4):

You have to go to your `web/index.html` file and add your google sign in meta tag:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

Comment: How do we get CLIENT_ID from google?

Comment: check this out https://www.balbooa.com/gridbox-documentation/how-to-get-google-client-id-and-client-secret. Just signup to https://console.cloud.google.com.

Answer (score 3):

In your web/index.html file, add a meta tag like the following substituting the YOUR_CLIENT_ID for the client id you get from google:
(other answer has typos)

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID" />
```

To get a client ID, you can find official google sign in directions here:

[Flutter Google Sign In for Web](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web)

[Get Your Google Client API client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid)